# Does Visual Studio have CSS intellisense?

Tags: visual-studio

I have Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio Code but I don't have intellisense for CSS. Does Visual Studio support intellisense for CSS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image]Yes. Basically.  When editing a .css file, and creating a style, and I type "font-"  I will get intellisense that gives me options to auto complete with options like "font-family" and "font-size".  When I type "border:", I'll get intellisense showing me possible values such as "dashed", "dotted", and "none" etc.

Comment: Yes, that I have... I was wonder if I should also have CSS intellisense when editing the html file... so when I type class="", I would like to see all the classes names.

Answer (score 0):

I was not getting CSS intellisense with VS2022. I checked it was resharper that disabled the CSS intellisense by default. I have to explicitly enable it[image]